# find element in html page by id via python from variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

guys i write a code for extract some data from my site by find element id and i get the post id from my data base and save in a variable but it just return None !!!

this is the HTML Codes:and i get the post id from db as int `18448` but i shuold make the true format for html id like this `post-18448`

```
<article class="post-18448 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-tv-shows" id="post-18448">
```

and the python code is :

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as wsoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as wreq


lucas_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user="root",
    password="xxxxxxxxxxx",
    database="Lucas_database")

mycursor_mov = lucas_db.cursor()
mycursor_mov.execute(
    "SELECT Post_ID FROM Lucas_t_db WHERE Post_ID IS NOT NULL AND Post_status IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Published_Time ASC ") #AND Post_ID IS NOT NULL AND Post_status IS NULL ")
myresult_mov = mycursor_mov.fetchall()

myresult_mov = [a[0] for a in myresult_mov]

print("DB post id query:",myresult_mov[-1:]

id_value = myresult_mov[-1:]

me = str(id_value[0])

print("none braket post id",me)

z = '"post-'+me+'"'
print("true fromat id: ",z)

url = "http://ezddl.com/"

url_req = wreq(url)
page_read = url_req.read()
url_req.close()

page_soup = wsoup(page_read, "html.parser")

Entry = page_soup.main.find('article',{"id":z})

print("extracted data",Entry)
```

the result of code is :

```
DB post id query: [18448]
none braket post id: 18448
true fromat id:  "post-18448"
extracted data:  None

***Repl Closed***
```

but when i set the `z` variable like this `z="post-18448"` the result of code is true !!!! :

```
*same codes*


z ="post-18448"

Entry = page_soup.main.find('article',{"id":z})

print("extracted data: ",Entry)
```

the result of new code :

```
DB post id query: [18448]
none braket post id: 18448
true fromat id:  "post-18448"
extracted data:  <article class="post-18448 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-tv-shows" id="post-18448">

***Repl Closed***
```

i cant get it why when i run the first code it gives me `none`  but the second code gives me true result

Answer (score 3):

Your element's `id` is not `"post-18448"`, it's `post-18448`. In your first example, you're arbitrarily adding double quotes to the string you're matching on. When you're defining it manually, you've removed those.

Drop the double quotes from your setting of `z`:

```
z = 'post-'+me
```